# Define class parameter with get() at Kotlin

Tags: class, kotlin, properties

I'm learning Kotlin and I've been stuck with this error for a while: I'm trying to define a class propertie `heat` based on another propertie `spiciness` using a `when` statement with the following code

```
14 class SimpleSpice{
15     var name: String = "curry"
16     var spiciness: String = "mild"
17     var heat: Int = {
18         get(){
19             when (spiciness) {
20                 "weak" -> 0
21                 "mild" -> 5
22                 "strong" -> 10
23                 else-> -1
24             }
25         }
26     }
27 }
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Error:(10, 29) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> Int but Int was expected
Error:(17, 21) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ??? but Int was expected
Error:(18, 9) Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public inline operator fun <K, V> Map<out ???, ???>.get(key: ???): ??? defined in kotlin.collections
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text
```

Additionally, the get() code is painted red with the following exeption:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> ??? but Int was expected. Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text.
```

Comment: Remove those braces around `get`. Kotlin seems to think you're setting that variable to a function. The getter can just hang below the variable. After the equals sign, you need an actual int value, though.

Comment: this resolved the first error, but ```get``` is still red with the exeption ```Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text```

Comment: It should be `val heat: Int get() = when (spiciness) { ...}`

Comment: look at the examples in the docs https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, you declared `heat` as `var`, without specifying setter.

Try this:

```
class SimpleSpice {
    var name: String = "curry"
    var spiciness: String = "mild"
    val heat: Int
        get() {
            return when (spiciness) {
                "weak" -> 0
                "mild" -> 5
                "strong" -> 10
                else -> -1
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!! For doing this correctly, should I add a set() method in the var declaration?

Comment: Yes, to declare variable you need to define setter:
`set(value) { }`