# When using ?.get to access parameter Kotlin raises an error Unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and I decided to program a simple text game.
When I try to access spawn rate of an enemy (does not matter witch) I always get an error:

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun MatchGroupCollection.get(name: String): MatchGroup? defined in kotlin.text
```

and the `.get` turns red in my IDE.

Here is my enemy dragon:

```
"dragon" to mapOf(
        "spawnRate" to mapOf("hill" to 1.01),
        "drops" to mapOf(
            "dragon scale" to mapOf("quantity" to listOf(1,10)),
            "dragon egg" to 0.01,
            "dragon head" to 1.01,
            ),
        "exp" to listOf(1, 4),
        "dmg" to listOf(35,75),
    ),
```

I am trying to access the spawnRate like this:

```
val dragonSpawnRate = mobs["dragon"]?.get("spawnRate")?.get("hill")
println("Dragon Spawn Rate: $dragonSpawnRate")
```

I tryed more ideas but all of them ended up with the same error.

```
    val dragon = mobs["dragon"]?.get("spawnRate")
    val dragonSpawnRate = dragon?.get("hill")
    //-----------------------------------------------
    val dragon = mobs["dragon"]?.get("spawnRate")
    val dragonSpawnRate = dragon["hill"]
```

I also tryed some solutions from this question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61660123/define-class-parameter-with-get-at-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com)

but none of them helped. I also tryed asking chat gpt but it did not hepled either.

Comment: That's not how you are supposed to use `Map`s. Create data classes to model your data.

Comment: What type does the compiler infer for `mobs`? In particular, what is the type of its values — and hence of `mobs["dragon"]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As their name suggests, collections are for storing collections of similar items. Maps are good for cases like e.g. mapping from user ids to user data. In this case every item is pretty much the same case.

In your example every item is an entirely different story: some of them are numbers, some of them are lists or other maps. Maps were not really designed for such a case. They can store such data, but we'll lose the type information, so we would have to cast values where needed:

```kotlin
val map = mapOf("foo" to 1, "bar" to "baz")
println(map.getValue("bar").length) // does not compile
println((map.getValue("bar") as String).length) // compiles
```

If we have multiple known fields of a very specific meaning, we shouldn't store them in a map, but in a class. In Kotlin we can use data classes for this:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val mobs = mapOf(
        "dragon" to Mob(
            spawnRate = mapOf("hill" to 1.01),
            drops = mapOf(
                "dragon scale" to Drop(quantity = 1..10)
            ),
            exp = 1..4,
            dmg = 35..75,
        )
    )

    // prints: 1.01
    println(mobs.getValue("dragon").spawnRate.getValue("hill"))
}

data class Mob(
    val spawnRate: Map<String, Double>,
    val drops: Map<String, Drop>,
    val exp: IntRange,
    val dmg: IntRange,
)

data class Drop(
    val quantity: IntRange
)
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if `IntRange` is a good idea here.

This is not really specific to Kotlin. This rule applies to pretty much every strongly typed language.